# Prove the existence of a sequence, spectral theorem??

Tags: functional-analysis

$T \in \mathcal{B} (H)$ is normal and $\lambda \in \sigma (T)$. Show that we can find a sequence $(x_n)$ in $H$ such that $\lVert x_n \rVert =1$ and $Tx_n- \lambda x_n \rightarrow 0$ where $\lambda$ is an approximate eigenvalue.

Can anyone offer any hints or show me the solution? I am new at Functional Analysis and I am having troubles using in practice the propositions related to the Spectral Theorem.

Comment: Isn't the definition of $\lambda$ being an approximate eigenvalue that the $T - \lambda$ is not bounded below?

Comment: But the interesting point is that the sequence should have all its terms such that $\lVert x_n\rVert =1 $

Comment: Being bounded below only depends on the unit ball. If there is a $c > 0$ such that $\|Tx\| \geq c\|x\|$, then for each with norm 1, we have $\|Tx\| \geq c$. Conversely, if $\|Tx\| \geq c$ uniformly on the unit ball, then given any $x$, let $y = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$. Then $\|Ty\| \geq c$ immediately yields $\|Tx\| \geq c\|x\|$.

Comment: But how did you use the fact that $T$ is normal?

Answer (score 1):

The role of $\lambda$ in the problem is not entirely clear. Does the clause "where $\lambda$ is an approximate eigenvalue" mean that $\lambda$ is **assumed** to be an approximate eigenvalue, or is it a part of the statement to be proved?

Anyway, every point of the spectrum of a *normal* operator is an approximate eigenvalue, see, e.g., [Proposition 2.2 here](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/hamhalte/malta07.pdf). This gives you the desired sequence (and as Zach L. said, it can be normalized).